# What is an ICollection?

Tags: c#, .net

What is a ICollection in C#?

```
private void SendEmail(string host, int port,
        string username, string password,
        string from, string to,
        string subject, string body,
        ICollection<string> attachedFiles)
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx

Comment: Have you tried to search it in MSDN?

Answer (score 10):

The `ICollection<T>` interface is the base interface for classes in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

The `ICollection<T>` interface extends `IEnumerable<T>` and is extended by `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and `IList<T>`.

An `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implementation is a collection of key/value pairs, like the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class.

An `IList<T>` implementation is a collection of values, and its members can be accessed by index, like the `List<T>` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I think what the OP is actually trying to understand, is what implements `ICollection<string>`, as obviously `new ICollection<string>()` isn't going to fly.

As Micah pointed out, `List<string>` implements `ICollection<string>`. If you want to know what else does, take a look at ILSpy, and find the `ICollection<T>` type, analyze it, and see what implements it. Here are some of my results

- ArraySegment
- List
- LisT.SynchronizedList
- LinkedList
- SortedList
- SortedSet

... and more

Also, a plain ol' `string` array also implements `ICollection<string>`

Answer (score 1):

ICollection is a interface that represents a collection, it also contains strongly typed members

Here is an example of how to implement that interface

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307484

The Generic List Implements this interface

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A collection is a group of objects that have the same type (string in your example).

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akyhke97%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Objects of any type can be grouped into a single collection of the
>   type Object to take advantage of constructs that are inherent in the
>   language. For example, the C# foreach statement (for each in Visual
>   Basic) expects all objects in the collection to be of a single type.

[ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx) is the interface definition for a collection.